# Typescript how to create a nested interface objects using mapped types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I want to have data that would be as follow

```
paymentProviderByCountry = {
    England: worldPay,
    Spain: worldPay
}
```

How do I create the interface for `paymentProviderByCountryObj` that integrates `paymentProvidersList` and `countryList` in my desired dynamic format.

I guess what I am looking for is how do I create recursively the obj

```
    enum paymentProvidersList {
    WorldPay,
    Paypal,
}
enum countryListEnum {
    England,
    France,
    Spain,
}

type T0 = { [key in paymentProvidersList]: string }; // This would work

/*
  I want the values on paymentProviderByCountryObj to be dynamic based on the
   enum values so that i can have an object that looks like this

  paymentProviderByCountry = {
    England: WorldPay,
    Spain: Paypal,
    France: WorldPay
}
*/
interface paymentProviderByCountryObj {
    // This is the complex case, i cant get the index of the class to be dynamic and also its value
    [key in countryListEnum] :string : { [key in paymentProvidersList]: string }; 
}

export interface sysConfigInterface {
    paymentProviders: paymentProvidersList,
    paymentProviderByCountry: paymentProviderByCountryObj,
    minPaymentThreshold: String,
}
```

[The Example Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20paymentProvidersList%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20WorldPay%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Paypal%2C%0A%7D%0Aenum%20countryListEnum%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20England%2C%0A%20%20%20%20France%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Spain%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20T0%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20paymentProvidersList%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20This%20would%20work%0A%0A%2F*%0A%20%20I%20want%20the%20values%20on%20paymentProviderByCountryObj%20to%20be%20dynamic%20based%20on%20the%0A%20%20%20enum%20values%20so%20that%20i%20can%20have%20an%20object%20that%20looks%20like%20this%0A%0A%20%20paymentProviderByCountry%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20England%3A%20WorldPay%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Spain%3A%20Paypal%2C%0A%20%20%20%20France%3A%20WorldPay%0A%7D%0A*%2F%0Ainterface%20paymentProviderByCountryObj%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20is%20the%20complex%20case%2C%20i%20cant%20get%20the%20index%20of%20the%20class%20to%20be%20dynamic%20and%20also%20its%20value%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%20in%20countryListEnum%5D%20%3Astring%20%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20paymentProvidersList%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%20%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20interface%20sysConfigInterface%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20paymentProviders%3A%20paymentProvidersList%2C%0A%20%20%20%20paymentProviderByCountry%3A%20paymentProviderByCountryObj%2C%0A%20%20%20%20minPaymentThreshold%3A%20String%2C%0A%7D)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `in` (introduced in TypeScript 2.1 as part of [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#mapped-types))

```
{ [key in countryList]: paymentProvidersList }
```

Or, in case you don't want to have to pass *every* country:

```
{ [key in countryList]?: paymentProvidersList }
```

Comment: Thank you for that. can you show me a workable example that would join the results aka `paymentProviderByCountry : { countryList : paymentProvidersList, countryList : paymentProvidersList}`

Comment: Literally put that directly after the `interface Whatever` and you're good to go.

Comment: "TS2464: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'." so i cant just put it there as they are enum

Comment: Apparently, it's only valid in literal types, and not directly under interfaces. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Bar%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Baz%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20T0%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20Foo%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0Ainterface%20T1%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%20in%20Foo%5D%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20T2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20whatever%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20Foo%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0A%7D. I learned something new today :D

Comment: Thank you for that but that assumes that the T2 knows key is set, whereas i want that value to be dynamic  check the link at the end of my question as is too long to post here

Comment: I guess the idea is that I declare something as T2 and then the rest of the Obj would know how the rest of the things should cascade to simplify my life

Answer (score 0):

This is what ultimately worked for my end goal

```
enum paymentProvidersList {
        WorldPay,
        Paypal,
    }
    enum countryListEnum {
        England,
        France,
        Spain,
    }

    // Or Record<countryListEnum, paymentProvidersList>
    type paymentProviderByCountryObj = { [k in countryListEnum]: paymentProvidersList } 

    const paymentProviderByCountry: paymentProviderByCountryObj = {
        [countryListEnum.England]: paymentProvidersList.WorldPay,
        [countryListEnum.France]: paymentProvidersList.WorldPay,
        [countryListEnum.Spain]: paymentProvidersList.Paypal
    }
```